# Nginx reverse proxy fails if location is not `/` with pypiserver

Tags: python, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, pypiserver

I'm trying to get a custom PyPI server running using [pypiserver](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver).

I tried to modify the example `nginx.conf` file in the README in order to use `/mylocation` instead of `/` and ended up with the following:

```
server {
    server_name mypi.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /cert/path;
    ssl_certificate_key /key/path;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /mylocation {
        auth_basic            "Howdy!";
        auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/pwd;

        proxy_set_header    Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass        127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

If I connect directly (via browser) to `http://mypi.com:8080`, the default welcome page of `pypiserver` pops up. If I try instead to connecto to `https://mypi.com/mylocation` it redirects me to `https://mypi.com/simple/` and throws a `404` error. I thought that the combination of `location` + `proxy_pass` was basically a way of saying "Connecting to `mypi.com/mylocation` is the same as `mypi.com:8080/`". Did I get this wrong? Or is the problem related to `pypiserver` itself?

If it helps, I'm on a Raspberry Pi with the following programs' versions:

- **nginx**: 1.12.2
- **pypiserver**: 1.2.1
- **python**: 3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A location block with `proxy_pass` just passes through the path unchanged unless you [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) it.

For your case add the following rewrite rule after the `proxy_pass` statement.

`rewrite ^/mylocation/?(.*)$ /$1 break;`